# 'Your connection is not secure' on google after update

Tags: firefox, ssl, hsts

After update to the latest version of firefox (52.0), when I enter on google.com* I get:

> Your connection is not secure

Without the chance to add an exception.

Without luck, I tried:

- Delete cert8.db and cert_override.txt
- Adding manually the line for google on cert_override.txt (obtained from another machine)
- Delete certificates (Options->Advanced->Certificates->Authorities->GeoTrust->**Google Internet Authority G2**)
- New empty profile
- Current profile refresh (firefox suggestion)
- New installation of firefox
- Cleared all Firefox history (with all options ticked)
- Change the date/time to 2015 and then back to 2017
- Use Agent switcher

My addons are:

- Enchanced Steam
- uBlock origin
- Instant translate: Select and translate
- Tampermonkey

I don't have plugins except for *Flash* (**Ask to activate**), *OpenH264* and *Widevine Content Decryption* with **Never activate**.

On the same machine, on google Chrome google works good and on another machine with firefox also works good, so, I think is not a firewall configuration.

**What else can I do to enter on google.com* on firefox en-US 52.0 (64-bit)?**

**EDIT:**
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
I have currently installed Trend Micro OfficeScan Agent as virus/spyware protection. I can't disable it because is a work machine.

On all browsers I have to configure a proxy. Here is the information:
(No proxy for internal addresses)
[image]

Comment: Try downloading a copy of Firefox Portable from PortableApps.com and see if you can reproduce your problem in it. Then announce the result here. It will help us isolate the problem.

Comment: @FleetCommand It is necessary? I tried with the binary version of firefox (decompress and use) and the result is the same. is a work machine and I don't want portable apps here. Thanks for your answer

Comment: You have tried everything that immediately comes to mind! Maybe if you do this, we get an epiphany. So, yes, desperate times requires desperate measures.

Comment: @FleetCommand ok, let me try that.

Comment: @FleetCommand Portable Firefox works same as normal Firefox installation.

Comment: Then the problem is nothing related to Firefox itself, or its certificate store. (Because the portable has a separate store.) Is this what you get? https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Fix-slowness-crashing-error/What-does-quot-Your-connection-is-not-secure-quot-mean/ta-p/30354

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show what information is available when you right-click on the browser to *View Page Info* and select the *Security* tab?

Comment: @FleetCommand The error is SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER. The mozilla support page for that error does not help me.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Added.

Comment: To me, it looks like you're not actually connecting to the authentic Google website. I was going to suggest checking the `/etc/hosts`, or using `ping www.google.com` to see what IP address is being used when resolving the `www.google.com` hostname. However, the fact that Chrome works correctly would seem to indicate that this isn’t the source of the problem. I would have thought that Firefox has cached a wrong IP address or has a web proxy configured but since you’re using a new empty profile, this is unlikely.

Comment: Is it possible that you’re using anti-virus software such as Avast, Bitdefender, ESET or Kaspersky and that this software is using a MITM proxy to intercept HTTPS traffic? In such cases, they might have installed a root certificate in the Windows certificate store. which is used used by Chrome (but Firefox manages its own set of root certificates).

Comment: See also: https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Fix-slowness-crashing-error/How-to-troubleshoot-the-error-code-quot-SEC-ERROR-UNKNOWN-ISSUER/ta-p/35758

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Before update, google works good. I only use firefox. Now I'm using chrome because with firefox I can't search or use gmail or login throught google+ on various sites. Something changes on the last version on firefox about certificates? As anti-virus, I only have *Trend Micro OfficeScan Agent*. Could I transfer certs from windows to firefox? Both browsers has a proxy configured.

Comment: It’s possible that other software previously installed a root certificate into Firefox’s certificate store and the recent update then subsequently restored the certs to the default set. You should [edit] your question to mention that you use Trend Micro and to provide further details on the proxy – and how it is configured.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55418/discussion-between-jotapdiez-and-anthony-geoghegan).

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan added chat for general discussion

Comment: Same problem since yesterday, also with Firefox 52, even with `-safe-mode`, with all Google domains (www.google.com, www.google.fr, goo.gl, www.youtube.com, etc.).

Comment: In my case, I've eventually found a workaround (but insecure): set security.OCSP.require to false, even though the error was not about OCSP (it was `SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER`).